# How to find the highest version of a nuget package to ensure its dependencies contain a specific framework version?

Tags: .net, mocking, nuget

I'm about to download [WireMock.net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WireMock.Net#dependencies-body-tab), but I need to use this package in a project with version 4.5 framework, and the latest version of WireMock.net does not support net45, and I don't know which higher version supports net45? How to find it? Is there any command to look for? I can only click one by one to view it.

By the way, Is .net's mock server best practice WireMock.net?

Answer (score 0):

The lowest .NET Full Framework which is supported by [WireMock.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WireMock.Net#dependencies-body-tab) is indeed `4.5.1`.

These frameworks are supported:

- net451
- net452
- net46
- net461
- netstandard1.3
- netstandard2.0
- netstandard2.1
- netcoreapp3.1
- net5.0
- net6.0

So you need to upgrade your test project to one of these versions, there is no need to upgrade your main project.